# Prove that the bounded set $\left \{ u \in End(E) | u(K) \subset K \right \}$ is closed.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

*Question:*
Let $E$ a vector field ( $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) of dimension $n$ and $K$ a compact convex set of $E$ s.t. $Vect(K)=E$. Moreover for the set $End(E)$ we define the following norm: $\left \|u  \right \|_\infty = max\left \{ ||u(e_i)||, i=1,...,n \right \}$ for $e_i$ a basis of E.
We know that the following set $F = \left \{ u \in  End(E) | u(K) \subset K \right \}$ is bounded, now proved that $F$ is closed.

I try different ways: by avsurd approach, by matrix representation of linear mapping approach, by definition... but I am very stuck here. Any help will be very nice.

Comment: Is $\operatorname{Vect}(K)$ the span of $K$? Also you should add your attempts to the question instead of just listing approaches.

Comment: @ronno Thank you for your time . If I am not wrong $Vect(K)$ is the span of $K$ too as $K$ is include in $E$

Comment: @ronno Moreover most of my post are solution verification and I always writte what I ve done in the question. Simply in this case all the attemps that I ve done seem to me so ridiculous that i don't see any benefit of writting them here. If you have any tips I will take it with pleasure.

Comment: Have you tried the case $n = 1$ and $K$ singleton (other than $0$)? $n$ general and $K$ finite? $n = 1$ and $K$ general?

Comment: @ronno what does it mean?

Comment: What does what mean? "singleton (other than $0$)"? That means $K = \{x\}$ for some $0 \ne x \in E$.

Comment: @ronno Thk a lot for your help right now I cannot think deeper on this problem but i will do it as soon as I can. If you can/want to writte a more details answer in the answer part I will be happy to read it and to base myself on it in order to writte a full details answer by my own (I will of course choose your answer to mark the problem as solved). Again thank a lot for your time, until now you ve been the only one to help me :-)

Comment: @ronno I forgot to mention that K is convex

Comment: Convex seems a strange condition over $\mathbb{C}$. Ignore the "$K$ finite" special case.

Comment: @ronno I think that I ve found a simple and different answer and I hope that it is correct I hope to read your feedback on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that I ve found a simple answer and I hope that it is correct I hope to read your feedback on it. take in count that I am just a student that is trying to answer a question he was stuck on it :-) .

*My solution:*
-First of all let remind that the set of all linears mapping on the vector field $E=E( \mathbb{F} )$ (with $\mathbb{F}$ the mathematic field equal to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) of finite dimension $N$ is equivalent to the set of all matrix $\mathbb{F}^{N \times N}$ as we know to every linear mapping corresponds a matrix representation. So we can writte that the set $End(E)$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{F}^{N \times N}$. This help us because we know that the set $\mathbb{F}^{N \times N}$ is a vector space of dimension $N^2$.

-Now as we know that $||.||_{\infty} $ is a metric we get that $(\mathbb{F}^{N \times N}, ||.||_{\infty})$ is a finite vector space normed space.

-It is very useful because [we know](https://www.bibmath.net/ressources/index.php?action=affiche&quoi=agreginterne/cours/complementstopo.html) that any subspace of a finite dimentional normed vector space is closed. And of course $F = \left \{ u \in  End(E) | u(K) \subset K \right \}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^{N \times N}$ (as it concentrates only on a specific linear mapping) hence $F$ is closed.

EDIT 1 : I get an answer from my professor and despite the down vote the answer is correct.
EDIT 2 : In the website we used the following property "all finite sub space of a vectorial normed space is closed."

Comment: $F$ will never be a vector subspace of $\operatorname{End}(E)$ since it contains $\mathrm{id}$ and is bounded.

Comment: @ronno who said that $F$ will be a vector sub space??? I just said that it is a  finite dimensional subspace .

Comment: Then I don't know what you mean by "subspace" and "finite dimensional"

Comment: @ronno subspace like a sub set

Comment: @ronno you re right there was a typo mistake. I did not call the right theorem. It is the vector normed space that must has a finie dimension (like this is the case here) not the subspace/sub set of it.

Comment: What meaning of subspace are you using such that (1) $F$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^{N \times N}$ and (2) all subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space are closed? (1) does not work for linear subspaces, and (2) does not work for all subsets.

Comment: @ronno  I don't know if I understood you correctly but my reasoning it is yes working with the property given in the sources. It was basically one of my test question and I ve answered the same thing and get all the points.

Comment: @ronno more precisally " Tout sous-espace de dimension finie d'un espace vectoriel normé est fermé." translation : "all finite sub space of a vectorial normed space is closed." Hence $F$ is closed as a sub space of $ \mathbb{F} ^{N \times N}$ where is the error??? This property is too in my course. https://www.bibmath.net/ressources/index.php?action=affiche&quoi=agreginterne/cours/complementstopo.html

Comment: In that statement subspace means vector subspace/linear subspace and $F$ is not one of those